# C# Index was outside the bounds of the array on windows 7 x32

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I uses this code to get all mdf files in a folder

```
string[] Dbfiles = Directory.GetFiles(c.Path + c.CompanyName + c.ProgramTitle, "*.mdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); MessageBox.Show(Dbfiles[Dbfiles.Length-1]);
```

works fine on windows 7 and 10 x64 but it gives me Index was outside the bounds exception on windows 7 x32 
i tried

```
MessageBox.Show(Dbfiles[0]);
```

and other stuff but it doesn't work i uses dot net framework 3.5

ForEach fix it

```
foreach (string file in Dbfiles)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
                {
                    //escape
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    c.MdfFilePath = file;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Directory.GetFiles** returns empty string[] and then you try to get element with **"-1"** index.

Just try to check the length of the array before accessing its elements.

Comment: i already tried that also with index as "0" still get the same error

Comment: it's an empty array, no elements at all. ***0*** index - first element.

Comment: i know, i can see it had at least one element from the break piont with the path i want still get exception only on windows 7 32bit, 64bit and 10 64bit works fine with the same code.
for loop also works when i replace the index number with a variable but also doesn't return any strings from the array but foreach loop sure works with the same codes